# Moving cell to another based on data from a different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns i'm trying to work with here, D, E, & F.  This is all on the same sheet.  Cell D2 &  down contains data. F2 & down has dates in some cells and blanks in others. What i'm looking to do is if any cell in Column F2 & down contains a date, cut/paste the corresponding cell data in column D2 to E2.  I don't want to just copy and paste because I would like the info to be removed from D2.

I'm not looking for a formula here as i'm doing this in line with other vba tasks.  The examples below are original at top and what I'm looking for at the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.  Sorry I don't have any code as I already looked around but was getting confused.

```
 C      D        E       F  
MFR    Cat#     IVC#    Date
MMM    1           
MMM    721490         10/19/17
MMM    2
MMM    723355         10/20/17
MMM    702107         10/20/17
MMM    702645         10/21/17
MMM    3            
MMM    4           
MMM    745824         10/12/17





 C      D        E       F  
MFR    Cat#     IVC#    Date
MMM    1           
MMM            721490   10/19/17
MMM    2
MMM            723355   10/20/17
MMM            702107   10/20/17
MMM            702645   10/21/17
MMM    3            
MMM    4           
MMM            745824   10/12/17
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:

```
Sub IsDateInCell()
  Dim countRows As Long
  Dim i As Long
  countrow = Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlDown)).Count

  For i = 1 To countrow
    If IsDate(Cells(1 + i, 6)) Then
        Cells(1 + i, 4).Cut
        Cells(1 + i, 5).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you will start this range in row 1. You can set the starting cell at the "Set rng" line, change "B1" to whatever your true first cell of the range.  Further, this assumes that your range is not directly bordered by any other information (in other words, the range is isolated) The subroutine uses a simple loop through each cell in the range, when the conditions of the 'IF' are true then the cut/paste will occur.

I added "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" in case your actual  row count is very large.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Dim nMFR As Long
Dim nCAT As Long
Dim nIVC As Long
Dim nDATE As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rng = Range("B1").CurrentRegion

nDATE = rng.Columns(rng.Columns.Count).Column
nMFR = nDATE - 3
nCAT = nDATE - 2
nIVC = nDATE - 1

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Row > 1 And cell.Column > nMFR And Cells(cell.Row, nDATE) <> "" And Cells(cell.Row, nIVC) = "" Then
        Cells(cell.Row, nCAT).Cut Destination:=Cells(cell.Row, nIVC)
    End If
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
Sub Main()
    With Range("F2", Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        .Offset(, -1).Value = .Offset(, -2).Value
        .Offset(, -2).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Thank you very much.  This worked perfectly

Comment: @T.Smith, please take your time to give proper feedback. Thank you